# Jest error: Cannot find module 'lightning/alert' from '.../newAccount.test.js'

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-jest

When I run the test for my LWC I have this error:[image]

I read about other issues like that where the solution is to mock the missing function but I cant find something related to action [in the repo](https://github.com/salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest/tree/master/src/lightning-stubs)

my package.json dependencies is :

```
"@cparra/apexdocs": "2.5.0",
"@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest": "1.1.0",
"@salesforce/sfdx-scanner": "2.13.5",
"sfdx-cli": "7.157.0",
"sfdx-git-delta": "5.3.0",
"sfpowerkit": "4.0.3",
"shelljs": "^0.8.4"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct. If the stub is not provided for a standard module in the sfdx-lwc-jest repo, you'll need to create your own. Luckily, the [lwc-recipes](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes) contains an example specifically for [alert](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/main/force-app/test/jest-mocks/lightning/alert.js).

```js
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class Alert extends LightningElement {
    static open() {
        throw new Error(
            'The LightningAlert documentation contains examples for mocking .open in Jest'
        );
    }
    @api label;
    @api message;
    @api theme;
    @api variant;
}
```

You'll also want to update your [jest.config.js](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/main/jest.config.js) file which will point the import to your stub.

```js
const { jestConfig } = require('@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest/config');
module.exports = {
    ...jestConfig,
    moduleNameMapper: {
        ...
        '^lightning/alert$':
            '<rootDir>/force-app/test/jest-mocks/lightning/alert',
        ...
    },
    testTimeout: 10000
};
```

The above pattern is covered in [Jest Test Patterns and Mock Dependencies](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.unit_testing_using_jest_patterns) under [Module Imports](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.unit_testing_using_jest_patterns#:%7E:text=%7D)%3B-,Module%20Imports,-To%20create%20references)